Direction for solving 3rd order non-linear ode $f(f''' - f'') + f'^2 = 0$
What the title says - I was playing around with an equation and I ended up with the following $$ f(f''' - f'') + f'^2 = 0$$
It's nice because all the coefficients are $1$ I think, but that might not be exactly true either because of how it's multiplied. I've played around with it a bit but it's weird enough that I can't really make much progress on this. I did find that a solution for this is $f = c$ where $c$ is a constant. Then I get $c(0) + 0 = 0$ which is true but also doesn't feel like it's a complete solution.
Is there a chance I could get some advice on how to proceed with this?

Try substitution $y' = p(y)$.

Not every DE has a symbolic solution, it is rather the rare exception. So randomly creating expressions will almost surely end up with a DE without symbolic solution. Try the equation in WolframAlpha, their symbolic engine incorporates all known tricks for DE transformations, so if that fails then you would have to invent a new technique. // Try also $f=e^G$, $G'=g$. This should result in an explicit equation for $g$ of one order less. But the expression will have higher degree.

Give me a nonlinear ODE and I will transform it to an Abel equation of the second kind.... let $f=\exp(U)$, giving $u''_{xx}+3uu_x'-u'_x+u^3=0$, where $u=U'$. Take $u'_x=z(u)$, giving an Abel equation of the second kind $zz'_u+(3u-1)z+u^3=0$, to which I find no solutions in the Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations.
